# error occurred when I using RxSwift's DelegateProxy with FSCalendar

Tags: swift, delegates, rx-swift, fscalendar

RxFSCalendarDelegateProxy.swift

```
import Foundation
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
import FSCalendar

class RxFSCalendarDelegateProxy: DelegateProxy<FSCalendar, FSCalendarDelegate>, DelegateProxyType, FSCalendarDelegate {
    static func registerKnownImplementations() {
        self.register { (calendar) -> RxFSCalendarDelegateProxy in
            RxFSCalendarDelegateProxy(parentObject: calendar, delegateProxy: self)
        }
    }
    
    static func currentDelegate(for object: FSCalendar) -> FSCalendarDelegate? {
        return object.delegate
    }
    
    static func setCurrentDelegate(_ delegate: FSCalendarDelegate?, to object: FSCalendar) {
        object.delegate = delegate
    }
}

extension Reactive where Base: FSCalendar {
    var delegate : DelegateProxy<FSCalendar, FSCalendarDelegate> {
        return RxFSCalendarDelegateProxy.proxy(for: self.base)
    }
    
    var didSelect : Observable<Date> {
        return delegate.methodInvoked(#selector(FSCalendarDelegate.calendar(_:didSelect:at:)))
            .map({ (params) in
                return params[1] as? Date ?? Date()
            })
    }
}
```

MainViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import ReactorKit
import FSCalendar

class MainViewController: BaseViewController, View {
    
    typealias Reactor = MainViewReactor
    
    let calendar = FSCalendar()
    let label = UILabel()
    
    init(reactor: Reactor) {
        super.init()
        defer { self.reactor = reactor }
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func setupLayout() {
        self.view.addSubview(calendar)
    }
    
    override func makeConstraints() {
        
        self.calendar.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.bottom.equalToSuperview()
            $0.top.equalToSuperview()
            $0.left.equalToSuperview()
            $0.right.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
    
    func bind(reactor: MainViewReactor) {
        // MARK: input
        calendar.rx.didSelect.asObservable()
            .map { Reactor.Action.setDay($0) }
            .bind(to: reactor.action)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
        // MARK: output
    }

}
```

I am trying to change FSCalendarDelegate func to Observable to use ReactorKit.
But When I run this code, error occurred
"RxCocoa/DelegateProxy.swift:230: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"
I don't know how to fix my DelegateProxy. why aSelector is nil?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have discovered a bug. The code is crashing because FSCalendar is asking the delegate if it responds to a selector but the selector is `nil`. Neither FSCalendar nor RxCocoa is checking the selector for nil.

[I have submitted a pull request to the RxSwift repository to correct this problem.](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/pull/2349)

While waiting for the pull request to go through the system, you can sub-class DelegateProxy and override the offending method:

```
class MyDelegateProxy<P: AnyObject, D>: DelegateProxy<P, D> {
    override open func responds(to aSelector: Selector!) -> Bool {
        guard aSelector != nil else { return false }
        return super.responds(to: aSelector)
    }
}

class RxFSCalendarDelegateProxy: MyDelegateProxy<FSCalendar, FSCalendarDelegate>, DelegateProxyType, FSCalendarDelegate {
    static func registerKnownImplementations() {
        self.register { (calendar) -> RxFSCalendarDelegateProxy in
            RxFSCalendarDelegateProxy(parentObject: calendar, delegateProxy: self)
        }
    }

    static func currentDelegate(for object: FSCalendar) -> FSCalendarDelegate? {
        return object.delegate
    }

    static func setCurrentDelegate(_ delegate: FSCalendarDelegate?, to object: FSCalendar) {
        object.delegate = delegate
    }
}
```

As to why the `aSelector` is nil... When FSCalendar wants to use a delegate method, it first checks to see if the method has been implemented. If not, then it checks to see if a deprecated version of the method is implemented. If there is no deprecated version, then it will ask the delegate if the `nil` method is implemented. It feels kind of silly to me for FSCalender to do this, but apparently if this is done on a traditional delegate implementation, the OS responds with false. RxCocoa just assumes that no library would ever do this.